# How Do I Process objects in my custom linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I successfully made a linked list, but now I am having trouble processing it. What methods do I need to add to my FoodList class to be able to process my objects? For example, I need to have the user be able to choose to manually add food objects together so I can print a meal. Also, I can't use any collections classes from the java API. It all must be custom.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FoodList list = new FoodList();
    boolean keepGoing = true;
    int scanResultInt;
    try
    {
        //I/O stream
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("foodlist.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(br);

        Food hold = new Food();
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            list.add(hold = new Food());
            String str = scan.next();
            //str = scan.next();
            hold.setName(str);
            str = scan.next();
            hold.setGroup(str);
            int cal = scan.nextInt();
            hold.setNumCal(cal);
            double percent = scan.nextDouble();
            hold.setPercentDV(percent);
            list.add(hold);
        }
        //System.out.println("" + list.toString());

        br.close(); //close I/O stream
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println("I/O EXCEPTION: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
do  {
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("            Welcome to the Parkland Meal Selector"        );
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Enter the number of the menu option you would like to select:");
    System.out.println("        1) List food database");
    System.out.println("        2) Create meal by manual selection");
    System.out.println("        3) Create meal by random selection");
    System.out.println("        4) Remove foods high in calories");
    System.out.println("        5) Exit");

    scanResultInt = scan2.nextInt();
    switch(scanResultInt) {
        case 1: {
            System.out.println("" + list.toString());
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            System.out.println("Create-A-Meal Menu\n");
            System.out.println("Enter the name of a food you would like to add:\n");
            String foodWanted = scan2.next();

            /*while( != null){
                if(foodWanted.equals());
            }*/
            /*Food tmp;
            for(tmp = head; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
            {
                result += tmp.f;
            }
            return result;*/
        }
        case 3: {
            System.out.println("Create meal by random selection: \n");
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            System.out.println("Remove Food High In Calories: \n");
            break;
        }
        case 5: {
            keepGoing = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
while(keepGoing);
}
```

Here is my Linked List:

```
public class FoodList {

    // Class fields
    private FoodNode head;
    private int listCount;

    // Private inner class
    private class FoodNode
    {
        public Food f;
        public FoodNode next;
        public FoodNode(Food f)
        {
            this.f = f;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }


    // Constructor for LinkedList
    public FoodList()
    {
        // Initialize start of the list
        head = null;
        listCount = 0;
    }

    // Add method (adds a reservation to the linked list)
    public void add(Food f)
    {
        // Create a new ReservationNode
        FoodNode node = new FoodNode(f);

        // If this is the first node
        if( head == null )
            head = node;
        else
        {
            FoodNode tmp = head;
            while(tmp.next != null)
                tmp = tmp.next;
            tmp.next = node;
        }
        listCount++
    }
    /*public boolean hasThatFood(String food){
        boolean haveThat = false;
        FoodNode tmp;
        for(tmp = head; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
        {
            if (food == f.getName());
                haveThat = true;
        }
        return haveThat;
    }*/
    /*public boolean hasNext(){
        boolean hasNext = false;
        if(head != null) {
            hasNext = true;
            return hasNext;
        }

    }*/

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "My Foods:" + '\n';

        // Loop through all the reservation nodes
        FoodNode tmp;
        for(tmp = head; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
        {
            result += tmp.f;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And my Food class

```
        public class Food {
    private String name;
    private String group;
    private int numCal;
    private double percentDV;

    public Food() {//String name, String group, int numCal, double percentDV
        /*this.name = name;
        this.group = group;
        this.numCal = numCal;
        this.percentDV = percentDV;*/
        name = "";
        group = "";
        numCal = 0;
        percentDV = 0.0;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public int getNumCal() {
        return numCal;
    }

    public void setNumCal(int numCal) {
        this.numCal = numCal;
    }

    public double getPercentDV() {
        return percentDV;
    }

    public void setPercentDV(double percentDV) {
        this.percentDV = percentDV;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Food{" +
                "name: '" + name + '\'' +
                ", Food Group: '" + group + '\'' +
                ", Calories:  " + numCal +
                ", Daily Percent: " + percentDV +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I know this is spaghetti code, but this is my last resort. Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: Can you please clarify your example, I am not getting what excatly your question means. Please provide a better explanation

Comment: My program creates a linked list of Food objects (singly linked). I just want to know how to operate on the objects in my linked list. If they were stored in an array list I would use a for-each loop. I understand that linked lists are not iterable though. So, I need a different solution.

Comment: So you want to iterate through the linked list ? to next element right ?

Answer (score 1):

To operate on the objects you have to write your custom `Iterator`. I guess here is nothing criminal to open `LinkedList` source and look how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, You can find many resource online,

https://crunchify.com/how-to-implement-a-linkedlist-class-from-scratch-in-java/

Here is one.

```
public Object getElement(int index)
{
    if (index < 0)
        return null;
    Node Current = null;
    if (head != null) {
        Current = head.getNext();
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if (Current.getNext() == null)
                return null;

            Current = Current.getNext();
        }
        return Current.getData();
    }
    return Current;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented some complicated classes. Inner logic of its is not very clear like your issue. So almost any answer will not cover your needs.

If I would you I would try recommend the logic using java core tools (without implementing classes, that implemented in best way `LinkedList`, `ArrayList`...). Logic should be converted into some structural solution. For example:

- enter point creates and calls your `stream service` to handle provided input stream;
- `stream handler` should manipulate [`builder`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern);
- [`builder`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) result have to be collected into [`composite`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern);
- and so on...

If you provide your logic in more structural way you would ask more clear question pointing the issue. Also I believe your question will disappear after this preparation.

---

Also I would recommend you to get familiar with next [GoF patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns): [`builder`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), [`factory method`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), [`composite`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), [`strategy`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).